# Issue with Apex Charts rendering twice JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, apexcharts, donut-chart

I am displaying two apexcharts in two different containers. But it displays 2 charts in each container. I checked there is nothing in my code that renders the chart two times.

This is my code. Please tell me what is the issue.

```
 
async function userPieChart() {
    // Call the asynchronous function and wait for the result
    let userStat =  await userStats()
    let brandPieData = {
        series: [],
        labels: []
    }
    let pLPieData = [];

    if( Object.keys(userStat).length > 0){
        let dataObj = userStat.brand_distribution || [];
        let pLdataObj = userStat.profile_loss_distribution || [];
        pLPieData = [pLdataObj.profit, pLdataObj.loss]

        if(dataObj.length > 0){
            dataObj.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b.dcount - a.dcount;
              });
            dataObj.forEach(obj => {
                let temp = {
                    series: obj.dcount ,
                    labels: obj.Brand || '',
                }

                brandPieData = {
                    ...brandPieData,
                    series: [
                        ...brandPieData.series,
                        temp.series
                    ],
                    labels: [
                        ...brandPieData.labels,
                        temp.labels
                    ]
                }

            })
        }
    }
  
        var brandOptions = {
            chart: {
                height: 150,
                width: 350,
                type: 'donut',
            },
            series: brandPieData.series,
            labels: brandPieData.labels,
            legend: {
                show: true,
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              }
        }

        
        var ProfileLossOptions = {
            chart: {
                height: 150,
                width: 350,
                type: 'donut',
            },
            series: pLPieData,
            labels: ['profit', 'loss'] ,
            legend: {
                show: true,
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
            },
            stroke: {
                show: false,
                colors: ['transparent'],
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              }
            
        }
        
        if(document.querySelector("#top-brand-chart")){
            var bchart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#top-brand-chart"), brandOptions);
            bchart.render();
        }
        

        if(document.querySelector("#top-profileLoss-chart")){
            var plchart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#top-profileLoss-chart"), ProfileLossOptions);
            plchart.render();
        }
  }
```

It was working fine when i was displaying one chart

userStats return data like this

```
brand_distribution:[
{dcount: 1, Brand: 'A'},
{dcount: 2, Brand: 'B'},
...
],
profile_loss_distribution:{
profit: 120.
loss: 20
}
}
```

userStats is an asynchronous function.

Comment: 1. change the second if to else if, see what happens

Comment: 2. show us your html

Comment: I would like to know how and where `userPieChart()` is called. Could you share this?

Comment: Now it is working. may be it was apexchart bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but in ReactJS. I got around it by using `chart.destroy()` method after `chart.render()`. In your case you can return the destroy method at the end of the function like

```js
return () => {
            chart.destroy();
        }
```